# how to animate images in a stackPanel wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, animation, storyboard

i'v developed few windows phone applications, but never interacted with the `animation`.
now i required a animation in a tile, the `xaml` is given below

```
<Grid Height="250">
                        <StackPanel Height="700" x:Name="stackPanel" VerticalAlignment="bottom">
                            <Image Width="50" Height="50" Stretch="Fill" Source="http://localhost:5141/Images/28/28_f6bce20b-cb91-41d8-80fb-36524e1e6e46_ProfilePic.jpg"></Image>   
                            <Image Width="50" Height="50" Stretch="Fill" Source="http://localhost:5141/Images/28/28_0b3b5606-8cf3-4a33-8292-e62f7785a224_tes.JPG"></Image>  
                            <Image Width="50" Height="50" Stretch="Fill" Source="http://localhost:5141/Images/28/28_1c59768b-3419-48e4-805b-e78ca8d82b71_d.jpg"></Image>    
                            <Image Width="50" Height="50" Stretch="Fill" Source="http://localhost:5141/Images/28/28_f6bce20b-cb91-41d8-80fb-36524e1e6e46_ProfilePic.jpg"></Image>   
                            <Image Width="50" Height="50" Stretch="Fill" Source="http://localhost:5141/Images/28/28_0b3b5606-8cf3-4a33-8292-e62f7785a224_tes.JPG"></Image>  
                            <Image Width="50" Height="50" Stretch="Fill" Source="http://localhost:5141/Images/28/28_1c59768b-3419-48e4-805b-e78ca8d82b71_d.jpg"></Image>    
                            <Image Width="50" Height="50" Stretch="Fill" Source="http://localhost:5141/Images/28/28_f6bce20b-cb91-41d8-80fb-36524e1e6e46_ProfilePic.jpg"></Image>   
                            <Image Width="50" Height="50" Stretch="Fill" Source="http://localhost:5141/Images/28/28_0b3b5606-8cf3-4a33-8292-e62f7785a224_tes.JPG"></Image>  
                            <Image Width="50" Height="50" Stretch="Fill" Source="http://localhost:5141/Images/28/28_1c59768b-3419-48e4-805b-e78ca8d82b71_d.jpg"></Image>    
                        </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

in above the `Grid` `(Height = 250)` contains a `stackPanel` `(Height = 500)` which contains some `images`, but `Grid's` height is less than `stackPanel's` height, so all images in `stackPanel` cant be shown at a time, so i want to **rotate** this `stackPanel` in **upwards/downwards** , more illustrative `diagram` is given below

[image]

any help to appreciate ?
thanks

Comment: It would be somewhat more common to use an ItemsControl subclass, such as a ListView, for this sort of situation, rather than trying to do this with Grid and StackPanel.  The ListView might use a StackPanel (or, more likely, a VirtualizingStackPanel) as its ItemsContainer.

Comment: Take a look at the DatePicker source in the toolkit for an example of how to do this.